# When do you need precision with thread execution timing and how do you do it with Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

(Under software architecture/design)

I'm not sure how my question could be subjective but the message next to the title suggests that it is. 
I hope I'm not violating the rules here.

Under what circumstances or application would you need absolute precision with thread execution timing( thread sleep, back to life and execution with precision)?

And how do you guarantee that with Java ?

I was reading again Kathy Sierra's SCJP/OCP. 
It says

> Just because a thread's sleep() expires, and it wakes up, does not mean it will return to running! Remember, when a thread wakes up, it simply goes back to the runnable state. So the time specified in sleep() is the minimum duration in which the thread won't run, but it is not the exact duration in which the thread won't run.

Then how do you write code for something very critical that needs absolute precision in Java?

Comment: I believe you're looking for real time Java https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java

Comment: This question is more "too broad" than "subjective", because 1) it's asking for an open-ended list of examples (which usually isn't great on any SE site) and 2) "how do you guarantee that?" is a *very* broad question which probably can't be done justice in a single answer. It's better suited for a book, and since this is Java we're talking about, odds are there is a book that covers this (Joen's link is a good starting point though). If you have a specific, concrete problem that you believe you need better timing properties to solve, then we may be able to help with that.